How to Remove White Rectangle in Unity 2D Game Scene?
I am a beginner in Unity 2D and currently learning how to make simple games. I'm encountering an issue where a white rectangle appears in the game scene. I am unsure of what is causing this and how to remove it.
Image of the issue:

Image of Canva  :

Image of Text :

What I've tried:

Checked the camera and canvas setup.
Ensured that there is no UI element or sprite blocking the view.
Looked into the layers and sprite renderers.

Could anyone help me understand what might be causing this and how to remove the white rectangle? Thank you!

try turning gizmos off

we need to see the Canvas and loading-text GO. It might be that loading-text is a script that does that. There is no way for us to know.

@BugFinder wow , just removed white rectangle

@bolov I trned gizmos off it disappeared , I uploaded  Canvas and Text .

There is another solution which might be less invasive. Turning gizmos off, turns a lot of other useful things off too. Instead you can either selectively turn off Canvas and UI gizmos down the list, or go to the scene hierarchy and click on the eye to the left of the Canvas(es) gameobject(s). This will selectively hide the gameobject in full (including children). Or if you just don't want to be clicking on it by mistake, the little hand button filters the Canvas gameobject(incl Children) when clicking around in Scene View.

The eye and hand toggles only affect the Scene View.

@BugFinder that would work for the scene view .. but this seems to be the GameView so I don't think Gismos should be it...

@derHugo, well gizmos are clearly turned on, and available in the game mode as per the screen shot, so, and gizmos is available on my game window and shows some/limited gizmos so, it would seem to be related

@NPatch the gizmos button on the game window, is not the same one as the scene view.. So its not necessarily a bad thing..

@BugFinder ha! Yeah indeed Game View has Gizmos as well (didn't know but always had ^^) by default these are deactivated but OP apparently opted in without noticing ^^ Game View and Scene View have individual Gizmo settings

indeed...I hadn't noticed this was GameView.
